# Why $\hat{\mu}\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ implies $\mu$ absolutely continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

Let $\mu$ be a compactly supported probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Suppose that $\hat{\mu}\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $\mu$ must be absolutely continuous with respect the Lebesgue measure. How to prove ?

The Fourier transform $\hat{\mu}$ is given by
 $$
 \hat{\mu}(\xi)=\int e^{-2\pi i\langle\xi,x\rangle}d\mu(x).
 $$

Thank you and sorry if my English wasn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Prove that $\mu$ has a $L^2$ Lebesgue density.
Then conclusion is trivial since

$$\mu(E) = \int_E f_\mu \ \mathrm d\lambda$$

Comment: How to prove $\mu$ has a $L^2$ Lebesgue density ?

Comment: Apply the Fourier inversion theorem to $\hat\mu$.

Comment: Can you give me a little more details of proof ? Because, I understand a litter about Fourier analysis. I will appreciate it if you can help me.   Fourier inversion theorem requires that functions  $f\in S(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: @user130405 You don't need the Schwartz version of the theorem. There is one for $L^2 \to L^2$. With different scaling (factor $(2\pi)^{-n/2}$) the fourier transform is an isometry on $L^2$. But all you need is that $\hat\mu \in L^2$ implies $\mathcal{F}^{-1} \hat\mu \in L^2$

Answer (score -1):

If you provide the definition of absolutely continuous measures, you will be able to prove it.

Comment: A measure $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to another measure $\nu$ if $\mu(E)=0$ for every set with $\nu(E)=0$  (i.e. $\nu(E)=0\Rightarrow\mu(E)=0$).  Sorry, I can not prove it. Could you help me ?

Comment: Oh sorry, your question is much more difficult than I thought. I was thinking about absolute continuity when you have the density but your question is not about this. Appologize