# How to use $L^2$ Lebesgue density of a measure $\mu$ to conclude that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, absolute-continuity

I am looking for an answer to the question: [Why $\hat{\mu}\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ implies $\mu$ absolutely continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2058291/877219).

Namely, let $\mu$ be a compactly supported probability measure (or a finite measure for that matter) in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and suppose that $\widehat{\mu}\in L^2\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)$. Show that $\mu$ is then absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

The only answer to the aforementioned post ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059555/877219)) claims that the conclusion is trivial as long as we know that the measure $\mu$ has "$L^2$ Lebesgue density". I have not managed to find material which would discuss the connection between the $L^p$ Lebesgue density and absolute continuity of a measure w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure. Therefore I am looking for a proof or a reference of the original claim and reference(s) to better understand the connection between the Lebesgue density and absolute continuity. Thanks!

Comment: [$L^2\subset L^1_{loc}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_integrable_function#Lp_is_a_subspace_of_L1,loc_for_all_p_%E2%89%A5_1) + [definition of absolute continuity of a measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Definition_2).

Comment: You should read about $L^{2}$ Fourier transforms in Rudin's RCA.

Comment: @geetha290krm Can you recommend some specific pages?